# can't transfer tiff or modi file with PHP

Tags: php, tiff, modi

this snippet should transfer file **tiff** or **modi** from web server to user by web

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: ' . $file_mime_type);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $file_size);

# till this moment all is fine
echo file_get_contents("path/to/file.tif");
# script fails on line above, and doesnt reach this place
```

when file format not tiff or modi, all works fine and client browser start downloading file (docx/xlsx/pdf/etc.)
when user try to download tiff or modi, script fails without any error.
Have tried **print(file_get_contents("path/to/file.tif"));** and **readfile("path/to/file.tif");** instead of echo, result is same

Comment: Do you have the MIME type set up for tif in your webserver?

Comment: Yeap, all types in config was set upped correctly, sry for time:)

Answer (score 0):

When i start use a "universal" Content-Type, all works fine

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); //universal Content-Type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $file_size);

echo file_get_contents("path/to/file.tif");
```